# Export outputs to excel

Tags: anylogic

I'm new to anylogic and I have a question about exporting outputs to Excel.

I have some outputs that are updated daily by an event. My goal is to export these values to Excel (in a database called output_testes) along with the date on which they occur.

I tried using, in my event's action block, the following function:

insertInto(estoques).columns(estoques.data, estoques.estoque).values(date(),Estoque_Refinaria).execute();

The Estoque_Refinaria output is occurring properly, however, the date outputs are not occurring - the spreadsheet remains with a blank column. Are there any suggestions to fix this error?

Comment: is your `estoques.data` column of type string?

Comment: no, the type is date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code call `date()` returns a String but your dbase column is set to `Date`.

Change the column type to String and it should work